# angular JS adding image gallery/viewer breaking single page routing

Tags: angularjs, routes, image-gallery

I am newer to Angular so this could be a really simple/stupid issue but after googleing and trying many things I couldnt get it to work.

I believe this may not be directly related to the image viewer but a general issue when trying to add additional functionality injected into the code (like this:  angular.module('app', ['angular-flexslider']);)  I tried with a couple other things and had same issue so it may be a general issue on how I have my code setup when adding this that is breaking everything including the routing (but routing is the only real functionality I have currently.

If I have stand alone pages for the image viewer it works fine but incorporating it with other code causes the issue.

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['angular-flexslider']);
```

if I change the "app"  to "app1" it does not cause all routing to break, so it is not the script tags being added that is causing the issue itself, but something with this and how I have the code setup (something is getting cross wired I think).

The code for my pages that are important are:
index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html ng-app="app">
<head>

    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">

    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="/images/DPLogo.jpg" />
            <h1>Downriver Panters</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="home">Home</a></li>                
                <li><a href="history">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="coaches">Coaches</a></li>
                <li><a href="activities">Activities</a></li>
                <li><a href="calender">Calender</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="fundraisers">Fundraisers</a></li>
                <li><a href="links">Links</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="styletesting">Test Styles</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-view>ViewPage</div>
        </div>
    </div>




    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; Copyright 2016
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- this is code for the image viewer that is causing it to break (but also add the app.js file below)-->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/flexslider/2.2.2/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

    <script src="/testing/angular-flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!--  end of code causing it to break -->


    <!-- my main control with the routing -->
    <script src="/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>

    <!-- have to put here??  so below mainCtrl???  cause not working if put on home page -->
    <script src="/controllers/homeCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/calenderCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/coachesCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="/controllers/galleryCtrl.js"></script>

    <!-- other file for routing that is causing it to break-->
    <script src="/testing/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

mainCtrl.js  (with my routing code)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);


    // configure our routes
    app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
      function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $routeProvider


            // catch all go home
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })

            // route for the home page
            .when('/home', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/about.html',
                controller: 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/history', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/hisotry.html',
                controller: 'hisotryController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/coaches', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/coaches.html',
                controller: 'coachesController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/activities', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/activities.html',
                controller: 'activitiesController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/calender', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/calender.html',
                controller: 'calenderController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/gallery', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/gallery.html',
                controller: 'galleryController'
            })


            // catch all go home
            .when('/fundraisers', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/fundraisers.html',
                controller: 'fundraisersController'
            })

            // catch all go home
            .when('/links', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/links.html',
                controller: 'linksController'
            })


             // route for the contact page
            .when('/contactus', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/contactus.html',
                controller: 'contactusController'
            })

             // catch all go home
            .when('/styletesting', {
                templateUrl: '/partials/styleTesting.html',
                controller: 'styletestController'
            })


            // happens when nothing specificed
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            })



            // not working/finding sites
            // if you don't wish to set base URL then use this
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: true
            });        

        }]);

})();
```

the code fot the app.js  (the control for the page for the image viewer:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angular-flexslider']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var ctrl = this;
    $scope.prod = { imagePaths: [] };
    $scope.prod.imagePaths = [
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg' },
        { custom: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg', thumbnail: 'http://flexslider.woothemes.com/images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg' }
    ];
});
```

Finally the partial for the image viewer/gallery page

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <flex-slider slider-id="slider" flex-slide="image in prod.imagePaths track by $index" animation="fade" animation-loop="false" sync="#carousel" slideshow="false" control-nav="false" init-delay="100">
            <li>
                <img ng-src="{{image.custom}}">
            </li>
        </flex-slider>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <flex-slider slider-id="carousel" flex-slide="image in prod.imagePaths track by $index" animation="slide" animation-loop="false" item-width="210" item-margin="5" as-nav-for="#slider" slideshow="false" control-nav="false">
            <li>
                <img ng-src="{{image.thumbnail}}">
            </li>
        </flex-slider>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to inject all of your modules in a single call, so you would use:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','angular-flexslider']);
```

The way you are currently doing it your module is destroy when add the second module to it.

Comment: ok, I understand what your saying.  So in my mainCtrl (where I delcare app (var app=...)  that is my first declaration  of it.  Then in my other Controls I am over writing that object first declared object.  So to do it the way I am not and have it work, I should not declare the app variable on every ctrl (since I did at the top of the main one),  just reference the app variable.  So remove  (var app = ...)  from all other controls?

Comment: Yes, so just edit your first declaration to match what I've done above.

Comment: I did that but now the angular code on the pages that use angular (simple code setting text based off textbox) does not work when I comment that out for the code in the control itself on individual pages?

Comment: You did it at the top right, before you tried to reference "app?" Open up the console, there's probably an error displayed there somewhere.

Comment: Also, you're loading angular twice in your script tags.

Comment: yes, I have the script tags on my index of the mainCtrl.js   then the other controllers  (homeCtrl.js) is is under that one.  The homeCtrl.js is where I removed the var app = ....     and in the console I am getting homeController is undefined   I am doing it like this::   app.controller('homeController', homeController);      Then I have a function under it that defines the homeController function

Comment: You have routing setup. All of the javascript should just be loaded in your index.html page and not repeated in the other pages.

Comment: I understand that for the function declare, but I wanted to have the controls for seperate pages in their own files to make it easier to see/read/etc.  So I have all the script tags on my index (see code above)  and I am declareing the function for each control in its own file (see app.js file above, I am not doing it quite like this in my code because I was still trying to get it to work).

Comment: Is it since the app controller /add code is in seperate files (even though it is auto executed as soon as it is read in the list of files, causing the issue?  You can see how I am doing it in my example above

Comment: Ok, well at any rate, the answer I posted was definitely the initial issue you encountered. I think you might want to narrow down what's happening now and ask a new question.